# How to add a new entry into a dictionary object while using Jinja2?

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I am not able to append add a new entry into a dictionary object while using jinja2 template.

For example, here I am using jinja2 template and I have created a **data** variable which is a dictionary. And after checking some *if* condition I ***want*** to append location attribute to the data object, e.g.:

```
{%- set data = {
                  'name' : node.Name,
                  'id' : node.id,
               }
-%}

{% if node.location !="" %}
    data.append({'location': node.location}) 
{% endif %}
```

However I could not find a way to achieve this and am getting the UndefinedError:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'append'

*Has anyone faced this issue or could provide a reference to solve this?*

I searched the web but could not find a solution i.e. how to achieve adding an entry to the dict object in the Jinja.

I have referred following and other web resources:

1. http://cewing.github.io/training.codefellows/assignments/day22/jinja2_walkthrough.html
2. [In Jinja2 whats the easiest way to set all the keys to be the values of a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352724/in-jinja2-whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-all-the-keys-to-be-the-values-of-a-dictio)
3. https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/27494

Answer (score 30):

Without the [`jinja2.ext.do`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/#expression-statement) extension, you can do this:

```
{% set x=my_dict.__setitem__("key", "value") %}
```

Disregard the `x` variable and use the dictionary which is now updated.

This also works for `len()` (`__len__()`), `str()` (`__str__()`), `repr()` (`__repr__()`) and many similar things.

Comment: hmm, does not work, with
```myString="{% set data={} %}{% set data2=data.__setitem__('key','value') %}{{ data2['key'] }}"; a=Environment(loader=BaseLoader()).from_string(myString); a.render()``` the output is `''`

Comment: @K.Frank, the answer says to disregard the variable that you assign to. `{% set data={} %}{% set x=data.__setitem__('key', 'value') %}{{ data['key'] }}`

Comment: I get `access to attribute '__setitem__' of 'dict' object is unsafe` when trying this (Python3, running [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/)=0.14.2)

Answer (score 21):

Dictionaries do not have the append method. You can add a key-value pair like this though:

```
{% do data.update({'location': node.location}) %}
```

or

```
{% do data['location']=node.location %}
```

Comment: Thanks Alpert! Though after using {% do data['location']=node.location %} or {% do data.update({'location': node.location}) %} I still got the TemplateSyntaxError, but after some searching on web I discovered my jinja environment was missing the jinja2.ext.do extention because of which that "do" tag was throwing the syntax error. Now it is working fine :) Thanks again!!

Comment: This link helped as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703013/how-can-i-modify-merge-jinja2-dictionaries

Comment: The first `{% do data['location'] = node.location %}` does not work for me, perhaps because `data['location'] = node.location` is not actually an expression and does not work with `do`, which expects expressions?

Answer (score 17):

Without the [`do`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/#expression-statement) extension:

```
{%- set _ = dict.update({c.name: c}) -%}
```

Works in base Jinja2 on Python 3, where the `__setitem__` solutions give me:

> access to attribute '**setitem**' of 'dict' object is unsafe

Comment: FYI - this works well for updating saltstack pillars with jinja 2 prior to state execution with python 3 clients.

Answer (score 13):

Key takeaways:

1. Dictionary does not support `append()`.
2. You can add the new item to the data dictionary by using the `{% do ... %}` tag:

   ```
   {% do data.update({'location': node.location}) %}
   ```
3. However, for the `do` tag to work properly you need to add the [`jinja2.ext.do`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/#expression-statement) extension to your Jinja environment.

Answer (score 6):

Without any of the extensions:

```
{% set d1 = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'} %}
{% set d2 = {'e':'f'} %}

{{ dict(d1, **d2) }}
```

Basically you merge the two dicts to create a new one.
As this doesn't use any extensions, it also works in Home Assistant.