# What is wrong with this jinja variable assignment?

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

My code:

```
 {%- set my_dict = {} %}
 {%- set my_dict['my_key'] = grains['id'] %}
```

Error message:

```
SaltRenderError: Jinja syntax error: expected token 'end of statement block', got '['; line x
```

Comment: this worked: {%- do my_dict.update({'my_key': grains['id']}) %}

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265291/11498682) answer, try this:

```
{%- set my_dict = {} %}
{%- set x=my_dict.__setitem__('my_key', grains['id']) %}
```

You can disregard the 'x' variable and keep using the dictionary.